# CSS combination: Applying letter spacing and rotation pops up the span

Tags: css, html, webkit-transform, letter-spacing

I have a div, and in it have spans, and their content are comprised of single letters

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        Set 4
        <div id="letterbox" class="letters"> 
            <span class="spanset4" id="item13">M</span>
            <span class="spanset4" id="item14">N</span>
            <span class="spanset4" id="item15">O</span>
            <span class="spanset4" id="item16">P</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you *just* apply rotation *or* letter spacing, it still looks ok

if you apply *both* rotation *and* letter spacing, the span it's applied to appears to be pushed up.

The result can be seen [in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devfingers/p0hLhath/)

I can correct it with padding as seen [in this other version of the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devfingers/p0hLhath/5/)

**But is there anyway to apply the CSS combination without the span to appear to be pushed up?**

Comment: What is the ultimate effect you are trying to achieve?

Comment: see the second JSFiddle of version 5 - that's the 'correct' result in 'Set 4' - characters precisely overlapping once rotated